# Re-closing hidden content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a large document where this is implemented A LOT. I am hoping there is a way to simply edit the JavaScript somehow, so I have less editing.

Basically, clicking on a line of text opens the hidden text beneath it. You can close and re-hide the text by clicking on that same line of text... THAT is the ONLY way I want it to operate. As it is now, you can click on the hidden text anywhere and that will also close it. That is becoming a problem because I have interactive content in the hidden text area, and an accidental click in the wrong area will collapse it all.

```css
.results_container {
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 21px;
}

.hidden>span {
  display: none;
}

.visible>span {
  cursor: default;
  display: block;
  line-height: 18px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 10px 0px 32px 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="results_container">
  Click Me to show hidden content
  <span>I am hidden in span tags. You can close me by clicking anywhere in this text, however, I ONLY want to close the same way I opened; by clicking "Click Me to show hidden content.</span>
</div>
```

[**Full Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/flipflopmedia/ejbdb128/5/)

NOTE: On the fiddle, my JavaScript is at the end, under the pasted-in jQuery... sorry, that's the only way I could get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the fiddle or below snippet:
https://jsfiddle.net/ejbdb128/6/

By checking against "this" in regards to the parent selector, you can filter out when you click on the child "span" element. I should note a caveat to this is if you click anywhere outside the "span" and in the div element, it will hide the span, even if you don't click just on the "Click Me" text..

```js
/* SCRIPT for HIDDEN DESCRIPTIONS for RESULTS */
$(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict";
  $('.results_container').addClass("hidden");

  $('.results_container').click(function(e) {
    if (e.target != this) {
      return false;
    }
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.hasClass("hidden")) {
      $(this).removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");

    } else {
      $(this).removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.results_container {
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 21px;
}

.hidden>span {
  display: none;
}

.visible>span {
  cursor: default;
  display: block;
  line-height: 18px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 10px 0px 32px 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="results_container">
  Click Me to show hidden content
  <span>I am hidden in span tags. You can close me by clicking anywhere in this text, however, I ONLY want to close the same way I opened; by clicking "Click Me to show hidden content.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Obviously, your script does work! :) Thank you. However, it is not working along with my complete setup. I should have added my complete code; I didn't think it would interfere. I have updated the fiddle and hope you can help further with this? https://jsfiddle.net/flipflopmedia/ejbdb128/7/

Comment: Brilliant Woodrow! Brilliant! I cannot tell you how appreciative I am for your help!! Thumbs Up!

Answer (score 1):

Add the click handler to to an external event and use that to hide . By the way, jQuery has built in functions `hide` and `toggle` for hiding elements.

HTML:

```
<div class="results_container">
<span class="clickme">Click Me to show hidden content</span>   
<span class="hideme">
    I am hidden in span tags. You can close me by clicking anywhere in this text, however, I ONLY want to close the same way I opened; by clicking "Click Me to show hidden content.
</span>
```

Javscript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
"use strict";
  $('.hideme').hide();

  $('.clickme').on('click', function() {
    $('.hideme').toggle();
  });
});
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/fLj6c4q7/

Comment: Thank you, but I was really hoping for just a JavaScript edit/fix. My document is over 10,000 lines and as I mentioned, this code is used a lot throughout, therefore, I am trying to keep from having so much to edit. Thank you!